# MultiRoute getSegments raw данные

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть мультироут вот такого вида

http://jsfiddle.net/zhzg0fy2/96/

Мы получаем все данные и даже форматированный вид каждого сегмента передвижений, типа:

> "Автобусы №№ 466, 677, 677к. До остановки «7-й автобусный парк» около 11 мин. в пути."

а как-нибудь можно получить эти данные в сыром виде? Без форматирования. типа просто `station: '7-й автобусный парк'`. Да, номера автобусов хранятся в другой переменной, время тоже. Это можно выдрать. а вот название станции?

=============

и второй вопрос. хочется чтобы была кастомная метка пункта назначения. ок. сделал вот так:

```
wayPointFinishIconLayout: "default#image",
wayPointFinishIconImageHref: "i/marker.svg",
wayPointFinishIconImageSize: [85, 105],
wayPointFinishIconImageOffset: [-42, -102]
```

все хорошо. а как можно сделать, чтобы по клику был бабл с кастомный контентом? сейчас по клику вызывается общая инфа о маршруте.

==============

и третий вопрос, а иконки транспортов где то есть в открытом виде? чтобы к ним можно было обращаться типа `yandex.maps/icon/{type}.svg` или что-то такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

По вопросам:

1. Названия остановок, через которые проходит маршрут, также есть в ответе. Из вашего пример:

   ```
   {
    type: "Feature",
    properties: {
     StopMetaData: {
     id: "stop__9995489",
     name: "Микрорайон Солнечный город"
     }
    },
   geometry: {
    type: "Point",
    lodIndex: 74
   },
   geometries: [
    {
     type: "Point",
     lodIndex: 74
    }
    ]
   }
   ```
2. можно создать собственный макет балуна, как показано [в примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_custom_balloon_layout?from=SO)
3. Иконки вытащить из API таким образом нельзя.

Comment: 1. Спасибо. 2. Этот балун работает по всему маршруту. А нужна только конечная точка. 3. Спасибо